# Can't use any filetype I try with Tkinter filedialog "filetype"

Tags: python, tkinter

So, I have this snippet of code:

```
def savefileas(self):
       filename = "hello.json" #Do interface
       f = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=("All files", "*."))
       if f is None: # asksaveasfile return `None` if dialog closed with "cancel".
           return
       f.close()
```

but, every time I try to run it, whatever i put on "filetype" (I've tried "json", "*.json", "All files", "*." and some others I've seen in examples around the web), it keeps returning with the same error on those lines:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tibers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "d:\Users\Tibers\Documents\GitHub\improved-broccoli\main.py", line 84, in savefileas
    f = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=("All files", "*."))
  File "C:\Users\Tibers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\filedialog.py", line 380, in asksaveasfilename
    return SaveAs(**options).show()
  File "C:\Users\Tibers\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\commondialog.py", line 43, in show
    s = w.tk.call(self.command, *w._options(self.options))
_tkinter.TclError: bad file type "*.", should be "typeName {extension ?extensions ...?} ?{macType ?macTypes ...?}?"
```

Why is that? and what do I need to do to fix it? (Preferably, I'd save the files as .json)

Comment: I'm guessing that you are asking it to look for filenames that are in the format "\*." with no file extension (.json). You could try "\*.\*" to indicate a wildcard before and after or *.json to indicate a wildcard + '.json'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [effbot](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112042657/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-file-dialogs.htm):

> filetypes
>
> list
>
> Sequence of (label, pattern) tuples. The same label may occur with several patterns. Use “*” as the pattern to indicate all files.

So `filetypes` should be a list of tuples of the form `(label, pattern)`. Right now you give it just one tuple, not a list of tuples. You can make it a list of one tuple or a list of multiple tuples, with the first being the default option.

So change the one tuple

```
f = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=("All files", "*."))
```

to a list of tuples like

```
f = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[("All files", "*.*")])
```

or to have Json instead of all files like

```
f = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[("Json", '*.json')])
```

or add all files as a second option with Json being the default like

```
f = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[("Json", '*.json'), ("All files", "*.*")])
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in my comment, I'm pretty sure your issue is simply with formatting.

```
f = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=("All files", "*."))
```

Should be

```
f = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=("json", "*.json"))
```

Or

```
f = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=("All files", "*.*"))
# I'm not sure you can do this one with asksaveasfilename though
```

Where "All files" and "json" are just labels

Comment: No, it doesn't seem to be that... Even when I try as you say, the error is still there

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more then! I'm not too versed on Tkinter but here are some examples that may lead you in the right direction: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/95889/tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfile

Comment: It's ok! Thank you kindly for all the help that you could give me, and for pointing me to some other examples! :)